# How to query an object which contains another object, in reactive PostgreSQL, Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, mutiny

I have a class RetailPlace, whose data is placed in retail_place table, and RetailPlaceAddress, whose data is in retail_place_address table. retail_place and retail_place_address connected via retail_place.id = retail_place_address.retail_place_id. I need to create a method which returns RetailPlace object with RetailPlaceAddress in it.
I tried to get RetailPlaceAddress first, and then to place it in RetailPlace object which I get next, but it didn't worked:

```
    public static Uni<RetailPlace> get(PgPool client, long id){

    return client.preparedQuery("select * from retail_place_address where retail_place_id = $1")
            .execute().onItem().transform(RowSet::iterator)
            .onItem().transform(iterator -> iterator.hasNext() ? RetailPlaceAddress.from(iterator.next()) : null).onItem()
            .transform(retailPlaceAddress -> new RetailPlace(client.preparedQuery("select * from retail_place where id = $1").execute()
                    .onItem().transform(pgRowSet -> new RetailPlace(pgRowSet.iterator().next().getLong("id"), pgRowSet.iterator().next().getString("title"), retailPlaceAddress))));
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what did not work? Error? Do you have logs? Side note: for such a use case, I would recommend to use SQL `JOIN` to avoid making two requests to the DB instead of one.

Comment: It says "Bad return type in lambda expression: RetailPlace cannot be converted to R".
If I use JOIN, how can I transform query results to two objects?

Comment: If it's a compilation error you must have an indication by the IDE of where it happens. When you use `JOIN`, you get all the columns in a single result set